# Pandas apply lambda to a function based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of rental data and would like to annualise the rent based on whether a column containing the frequency states that the rent is monthly, i.e. price * 12

The frequency column contains the following values - 'Yearly', 'Monthly', nan

I have tried - `np.where(df['frequency'] == "Monthly", df['price'].apply(lambda x: x*12), 0)`

However, where there is monthly data, the figure seems to be being copied 12 times rather than multiplied by 12:
[image]

And I need to have the price multiplied by 12 but can't figure out how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `price` column contains string and not numeric values.
If you load your dataframe from a file (csv, xlsx), use `thousands=','` as parameter of `pd.read_csv` or `pd.read_excel` to interpret string like `'4,500` as the number `4500`.

Demo:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

csvdata = """\
frequency;price
Monthly;4,500
Yearly;30,200
"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csvdata), sep=';')
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csvdata), sep=';', thousands=',')
```

For `df1`:

```
>>> df1
  frequency   price
0   Monthly   4,500
1    Yearly  30,200

>>> df1.dtypes
frequency    object
price        object  # not numeric
dtype: object

>>> df1['price'] * 2
0      4,5004,500
1    30,20030,200
Name: price, dtype: object
```

For `df2`:

```
>>> df2
  frequency  price
0   Monthly   4500
1    Yearly  30200

>>> df2.dtypes
frequency    object
price         int64  # numeric
dtype: object

>>> df2['price'] * 2
0     9000
1    60400
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are strings instead numbers floats in column `price`, so first replace `,` to `.` and then convert to floats, last multiple by `12`:

```
np.where(df['frequency'] == "Monthly", df['price'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)*12, 0)
```

If values are thousands separated by `,` replace by empty string:

```
np.where(df['frequency'] == "Monthly", df['price'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)*12, 0)
```